# On prime(less)ness and composite(less)ness of 1

Tags: soft-question, intuition

I was sitting in my room when suddenly my cousin came and asked me, "Why is $1$ neither prime nor composite". Well ofcourse, i was never given an explaination of that in school, it was just a convention. We assumed it.
Studying Metric Spaces the same evening I recalled how a set can be open as well as closed.
I knew from the beginning of the course

$1)$ Some definition of openness.
Later i came accross
$2)$ A set is open if its complement is closed.

Can't a similar argument be established for 1 being both prime and composite?

Please give your views on the topic.

Comment: In a more abstract setting, we would add zero divisors and units to the exclusive categories of primes and composites.  No prize for guessing which one of these 1 falls into.

Comment: As a set can be neither open nor closed, a number can be neither prime nor composite. $0$ and units are considered neither prime nor composite. That's much more convenient than positing $1$ were both, prime and composite. (Which one might do, nobody forces one to choose the most convenient definitions.)

Comment: You actually mention exactly the reason why it is neither prime nor composite: convention.  We define a number to be prime if it is unequal to 1 and has no proper non-unit divisor.  We say that a number is composite if it is non-unit and not prime.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental theorem of arithmetic states that every integer greater than 1 can be represented by a unique (up to reordering) product of prime numbers, and that is an elegant way to state it. But if 1 were prime, then the theorem as stated would be false; $3=3\times 1=3\times 1 \times 1 = \dots$ would be a counterexample. This would make for an uglier fundamental theorem of arithmetic. As far as I know, this is the main reason for the (relatively modern) convention of not including 1 in the set of prime numbers.

**EDITED TO ACTUALLY ANSWER YOUR QUESTION**

> Can't a similar argument be established for 1 being both prime and composite?

No. Because the definition of a prime number is: "a natural number greater than 1 with no positive divisors other than 1 and itself". Furthermore, one way to define a composite number would be: "a composite number is a natural number greater than 1 that is not prime". That is to say, the prime numbers and the composite numbers are mutually exclusive. There are no numbers which are both prime and composite.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you right off the bat that 1 is most definitely ***NOT*** composite.

But, how do you prove that the set of primes and composites is open? The only way I see of doing that is using circular definitions, and I don't know about you, but I consider circular definitions to be a fallacy.

If you want, you can try sending your argument to the author of this page: http://primefan.tripod.com/Prime1ProCon.html though I don't know if he's still updating that page. I think, I'm not sure, that I sent him my argument that prime numbers in $\mathbb{Z}$ have irrational square roots, though he does mention some other properties prime numbers have which 1 lacks. I find these facts far more convincing of 1's non-primality than any hand-wringing about one specific beloved wording of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.